# Proof n-th root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that any real number $k$ has $n^\text{th} $ root if n is odd?

Prove that any $ k>0$ has an $n^\text{th}$ root if n is even ?

Is there a hint to help me prove it?

Is the intermediate  value  theorem used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it should use the I.V.T.

Comment: Define 
$$
f(x)=x^n=k 
f(x)=x^n-k=0

$$
for $n$ odd. 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}x^n-k =\infty
$$ 
What about
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^n=-\infty
$$ 
  
Becaus f is continuous  and there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $$
 f (x_1) \le -M \le 0 \le M < f (x_2) $$
and from IVT  theres n-th root 
 
The same if $k >0$ and part b  , like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$
f(x)=x^n
$$
for $n$ odd.

What is 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}x^n
$$ 
What about
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^n
$$ 
Given any $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, why can we find an $x$ such that 
$$
x^n=y
$$
The procedure for $n$ even and $y\geq 0$ is the same.

Comment: $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}x^n =\infty $$ $$ \lim_{x\to -\infty}x^n =-\infty$$    and  0 between infinity and -infinty by intermediaries  theorem the k has n-th root

Comment: Correct. That's all there is to it, besides maybe noting that the function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Assume X={x$\in$R | $x^{n}$$\le$k} and define u=l.u.b. X. Then prove that $u^{n}$ can be neither $\lt$k nor $\gt$k.(for further reading, please refer to "Real Mathematical Analysis",Second Edition by Charles C. Pugh Chapter 1 Exercises 15,16)

Comment: This prove for IVT but in this question I use this theorem , this my solution :Define $$ f(x)=x^n=k f(x)=x^n-k=0 $$ for $n$ odd. $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}x^n-k =\infty $$ What about $$ \lim_{x\to -\infty}x^n=-\infty $$ Becaus f is continuous and there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $$ f (x_1) \le -M \le 0 \le M < f (x_2) $$ and from IVT theres n-th root The same if $k >0$ and part b

Comment: It depends on which principles you try to construct your proof. I mentioned the same characteristics that any bounded-from-above subset of R has a least upper bound.